# Timeout after X second in Python

Tags: python, serial-port, timeout

I am writing a program in python, which works like this:

1. Take input string through Serial port, when press enter (Carriage
   Return)
2. Check if `$` sign is present as the first character of input string then continue

> Problem

It can make a trouble if I didn't get the `Carriage Return CR`  and got another string at the same time or after specific interval of time.
In order to avoid this problem I want to add timeout session which makes the previous buffer `Null` after specific interval of time if Carriage Return not received.

kindly review my codes below and guide me on how do I add timeout option in it?

> CODE

```
import serial

x = [0,0,0]
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
buffer = ''
while True:
    buffer += ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
    if '\n' in buffer:
        if buffer[0] == '$':
            x1 = buffer.rstrip()
            x2= x1.split(",")
            print((x2[0]),(x2[1]),(x2[2]))
        buffer = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you just need to add this line at the end of program.
This line will add more 60sec every time you input correct string

```
clear_buffer = time.time() + 60
```

Check out below coding

```
import serial
import time

x = [0,0,0]
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
buffer = ''
clear_buffer = time.time() + 60
while True:
    if time.time() >= clear_buffer:
        buffer = ''
        clear_buffer = time.time() + 60
    buffer += ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
    if '\n' in buffer:
        if buffer[0] == '$':
            x1 = buffer.rstrip()
            x2= x1.split(",")
            print((x2[0]),(x2[1]),(x2[2]))
        buffer = ""
        clear_buffer = time.time() + 60
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be reading your question wrong, but it appears as though you just want to clear the buffer string after a set amount of time?  This will clear it every 60 seconds:

```
import serial
import time

x = [0,0,0]
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
buffer = ''
clear_buffer = time.time() + 60
while True:
    if time.time() >= clear_buffer:
        buffer = ''
        clear_buffer = time.time() + 60
    buffer += ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
    if '\n' in buffer:
        if buffer[0] == '$':
            x1 = buffer.rstrip()
            x2= x1.split(",")
            print((x2[0]),(x2[1]),(x2[2]))
        buffer = ""
```

Comment: I got a problem in your above coding, It is doing session timeout after 60 seconds forcefully...
but I want session timeout after 60sec if it didn't receive Carriage return